# Python in VS Code: Auto-completion (IntelliSense) not working for object instances in the editor tab

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to use VS Code as IDE, and it's IntelliSense (auto-completion) to improve the development.

But I find that the IntelliSense is not working for **object instances in the Editor Tab**.

I have the example on the figure below, where I created a figure and tried to access its properties via IntelliSense on the editor tab: the properties are not available, only variables.

What is curious is that: on the Python Interactive Tab, the IntelliSense (autocomplete) works fine, for the same object. This example is in the same figure below.

I've tried to disable the Jedi IntelliSense, but it didn't change anything.

[image]

The code used in the image is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
y = np.cos(x)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: auto-completion works fine for **imported modules**. For instance: If I type `np.` it shows functions of numpy package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it works in the interactive window is it is working against live data, and so Python itself can say what things should be. But in the editor windows it's all inferred via IntelliSense which is much harder to get right. If you tried both Jedi and MPLS as IntelliSense engines and neither work then I'm afraid there isn't much to do until one of them improves enough to work in that specific situation.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Maybe there is another extension that recognizes the written code. Do you suggest any Auto-completion tool? I'm testing some, named "TabNine" and "Kite". They seems to work fine.

Comment: We're currently doing a lot of work on the Microsoft Python Language Server that will hopefully improve things in the near future.

Comment: Wonder if any progress has been made on this issue? Seems like this is still a problem with Pylance too @BrettCannon

Comment: @hsl no progress and I wouldn't expect any in the short-term as this isn't something that's easy to do.